# Передать массив при помощи ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Имеется функция

```
function FilterCategory(id) {
    var options = $('select[name="options[]"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        data: {id: id, 'options[]': options},
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product/filter',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error.length > 0) {
                new Noty({
                    type: 'error',
                    layout: 'topRight',
                    theme: 'relax',
                    text: data['error'],
                    timeout: 2000,
                }).show();
            } else {
                $("#result").html(data.content);
                $("#hide").remove();
                $('#message').select2();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

И нужно как-то передать массив значений с разного кол-ва селектов:

```
<select name="options[]" class="small options" onchange="FilterCategory(39);">
   <option value="">---</option>
   <option value="78">Бланк (чистая)</option>
   <option value="82">Другое</option>
   <option value="79">Нюд без парика (голая)</option>
   <option value="80">Нюд с париком</option>
   <option value="81">Фулсет (в одежде)</option>
</select>

<select name="options[]" class="small options" onchange="FilterCategory(39);">
   <option value="">---</option>
   <option value="49">Готовая работа</option>
   <option value="48">Предзаказ</option>
   <option value="216">Работа для примера</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможен еще такой вариант:

```
function FilterCategory() {
    var form = $('#form');
    $.ajax({
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product/filter',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error.length > 0) { // eсли oбрaбoтчик вeрнул oшибку
                new Noty({
                    type: 'error',
                    layout: 'topRight',
                    theme: 'relax',
                    text: data['error'],
                    timeout: 2000,
                }).show();
            } else {
                $("#result").html(data.content);
                $("#hide").remove();
                $('#message').select2();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var options_wrong = $('select[name="options[]"]').val();
var options_right = $('select[name="options[]"]').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(',');

console.log(options_wrong, options_right);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options[]" class="small options" onchange="FilterCategory(39);">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="78">Бланк (чистая)</option>
  <option value="82">Другое</option>
  <option value="79">Нюд без парика (голая)</option>
  <option value="80">Нюд с париком</option>
  <option value="81" selected>Фулсет (в одежде)</option>
</select>

<select name="options[]" class="small options" onchange="FilterCategory(39);">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="49">Готовая работа</option>
  <option value="48">Предзаказ</option>
  <option value="216" selected>Работа для примера</option>
</select>
```